# Determining whether these sets are open, closed or neither

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of $n \times n$ invertible matrices open, closed, or neither?

My guess was that it was open.

Is the set of $n \times n$ matrices with determinant $1$ open, closed, or neither?

My guess was that it was closed.

Not sure of the reasoning though. Keep in mind both of these are $\subset$ $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: More generally, the set of invertible elements in a Banach algebra is open. This follows easily from the Neumann series.

Answer (score 5):

Invertible matrices = $GL_n ( \mathbb{R})$ = $det^{-1} ((- \infty , 0) \cup (0, \infty))$ Which is the inverse image of an open set and therefore open

Determinant 1 = $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ = $det^{-1}(1)$ which is the inverse image of a closed set and therefore closed.

Answer (score 4):

Think of open sets as those for which any element in the set has a neighbourhood contained in the set, and remember that determinant is a continuous function so that perturbing a matrix by a small amount won't change the determinant by too much.

If your matrix $A$ is invertible, it has a non-zero determinant, take a small neighbourhood $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ around $\det A \in \mathbb{R}$ which doesn't contain $0$.  Because $\det$ is continuous, the preimage of $N$, $\det^{-1}(N)$ is open.

To see it isn't closed, show that the complement isn't open in a similar way to the next part.

For those with determinant $1$, consider a perturbation of the identity matrix to see that no open ball centred on $I$ is contained in the set of matrices with determinant $1$.  To see it is closed, show the complement is open in a similar way to the first part.

Comment: Thanks. Makes complete sense. One question though. I understand that if no open ball can be contained then the set is closed. Why again is the matrices with determinant 1 closed? lol Maybe I didnt know what you meant by perturbation.

Comment: If no open ball can be contained in the set, then the set isn't open, but it doesn't mean it is closed.  To see the set is closed, see that the complement is open.  Take a matrix with determinant not $1$ and find a neighbourhood of it with no matrices in that neighbourhood having determinant $1$ either.

Comment: Also look at Sean's answer for a far more concise argument.

Comment: And lastly, by "take a perturbation of the identity", I meant we can take matrices arbitrarily close to the identity matrix but with determinant not $1$.  ie) $I_{n, n} + \epsilon \delta_{1}^1$.  This shows no open ball containing the identity contains only matrices of determinant $1$.